# BroadCast Reciever to detect video is captured from camera

Tags: java, android, background-service

Is there a way to detect through broadCast receiver (or any other way) when camera captured a video.

I have done the same for camera photo using below code :

**In Manifest :**

```
<receiver
            android:name=".CameraPhotoReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**BroadCast Receiver Class:**

```
public class CameraPhotoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(arg1.getData(), null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String image_path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));

    Toast.makeText(context, "New Photo is Saved as : " + image_path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

- What I want to accomplish is to upload the video from broadcast receiver's onReceive when new video is captured from camera.
- waiting to learn from your experience. Thanks in advance
- **Edit** : Specifically I have to achieve this only for videos captured from camera

Comment: :Just try for the camera button clik event on manifest  and check the output on broadcastreceiver class that the output is image or video..if it is video then perform the action of upload to the server.

Comment: @BornToWin plz a line or two of code can solve my issue

Comment: :I am not getting what are you talking about?

Comment: can I have a relevant code of one or two lines you just explained above.

Comment: "I have done the same for camera photo using below code" -- there is no requirement for any camera app to send either of those two broadcasts.

Comment: I am not working on Camera App.. final app is not camera app

Comment: @ZuhaibAhmed:No i dont hv any code i jst explain u an senerio you jst try with tht..hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a ContentObserver on the media URI as a trigger and then check the timestamp of the most recent video file in the media store?

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you lead me to any example that how can I achieve it with this.. or some code

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare in this way in the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".CameraEventReciver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```